# Returning undefined type of data on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

I have a jquery script which does ajax call to my action inside the controller in my MVC application:

```
$('#save').click(function () {
    $.post(url, { id: id, text: textarea.val() }, function (data) {
        if (data) {
            row.children('td').eq(3).text(textarea.val());
            row.children('td').eq(4).text('Da');
            row.children('td').eq(5).hide();
            $('#napomena').val('');
            form.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

And this is my controller:

```
  public ActionResult PravdanjeIzostanaka(string id, string text)
        {
            var obj = db.Odsutnost.Find(Convert.ToInt32(id));
            if(obj!=null && text.Trim()!="")
            {
                obj.Napomena = text;
                obj.Opravdano = true;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("PregledIzostanaka");
            }
            return null;  // what am I supposed to return here so that data type in ajax would be undefined??          
        }
```

As you can see im checking whether the obj object and text field are !=null and if its empty. If those two requirements are not met I would like to make a little  alert which would basically say: "Text field is required!" and modify my script to something like this:

```
 if (data!=="undefined") {
            row.children('td').eq(3).text(textarea.val());
            row.children('td').eq(4).text('Da');
            row.children('td').eq(5).hide();
            $('#napomena').val('');
            form.hide();
        }
else{
alert('Text field is required!');
}
```

So I need to modify my script and Action(action should return something which ajax would see it as undefined in order that I can do alert)...

Can someone help me out with this? :)

Comment: `"undefined"` isn't `undefined`. One is a string, the other one is `undefined`. You could do `typeof data !== "undefined"`, because typeof operator can give you `"undefined"`

Comment: okay but what do I need to return inside my action so it is typeof data === "undefined" in order for me to display the alert popup ? Its obviously not null cause its not working ...

Comment: I didn't realize `data` was the result of the AJAX. In that case, there's no way you can get `undefined` value.

Comment: Well it doesn't have to be undefined... Just something to check if the textbox is empty and do alert popup message... Doesn't matters if its client or server side.. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe return a 404 status code and manage it as an `error`?

Comment: Could you show me an example please? And how to handle it in data result??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return a json string as undefined. More like the below:

```
public ActionResult PravdanjeIzostanaka(string id, string text)
        {
            var obj = db.Odsutnost.Find(Convert.ToInt32(id));
            if(obj!=null && text.Trim()!="")
            {
                obj.Napomena = text;
                obj.Opravdano = true;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("PregledIzostanaka");
            }
            return json("undefined");           
        }
```

Comment: Finally!! Thanks!! Works like a charm!! :) :)